# Is there a way to force static fields to be initialized in C#?

Tags: c#, static, initialization

Consider the following code:

```cs
class Program
{
    static Program() {
        Program.program1.Value = 5;
    }

    static List<Program> values = new List<Program>();
    int value;
    int Value
    {
        get { return value; }
        set { 
            this.value = value;
            Program.values.Add(this);
        }
    }

    static Program program1 = new Program { value = 1 };
    static Program program2 = new Program { value = 2 };
    static Program program3 = new Program { value = 3 };

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (Program.values.Count == 0) Console.WriteLine("Empty");
        foreach (var value in Program.values)
            Console.WriteLine(value.Value);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

It prints only the number 5, and if removed the code in the static constructor, it prints "Empty".

Is there a way to force static fields to be initialized even whether not used yet?

I need to have a static property named Values with returns all instances of the referred type.

I tried some variations of this code and some works for some types but doesn't for others.

EDIT: THE SAMPLE ABOVE IS BROKEN, TRY THIS ONE:

```cs
class Subclass<T> {
    static Subclass()
    {
        Values = new List<Subclass<T>>();
    }
    public Subclass()
    {
        if (!Values.Any(i => i.Value.Equals(this.Value)))
        {
            Values.Add(this);
        } 
    }

    public T Value { get; set; }

    public static List<Subclass<T>> Values { get; private set; }
}

class Superclass : Subclass<int>
{
    public static Superclass SuperclassA1 = new Superclass { Value = 1 };
    public static Superclass SuperclassA2 = new Superclass { Value = 2 };
    public static Superclass SuperclassA3 = new Superclass { Value = 3 };
    public static Superclass SuperclassA4 = new Superclass { Value = 4 }; 
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Console.WriteLine(Superclass.SuperclassA1); //UNCOMMENT THIS LINE AND IT WORKS
        foreach (var value in Superclass.Values)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(value.Value);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer to your question is 'well, yes'. But one of the two ways of "forcing" it is what you're already doing.

The relevant section in the language spec is [Static constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/classes#static-constructors), and specifically:

> The static constructor for a class executes at most once in a given
> application domain. The execution of a static constructor is triggered
> by the first of the following events to occur within an application
> domain:
>
> - An instance of the class is created.
> - Any of the static members of the class are referenced.
>
> If a class contains the Main method (Section 3.1) in which execution
> begins, the static constructor for that class executes before the Main
> method is called. If a class contains any static fields with
> initializers, those initializers are executed in textual order
> immediately prior to executing the static constructor.

Comment: Yeah! I have read this in the specification too. But I was hopeful there was another, not oficial, way to do it.

Thanks!

Comment: If there is an unofficial way, I'd like to hear about it! But perhaps one should shy away from such techniques. `Unofficial.Equals(Hack)`?

Comment: @ChristofferLette For Rafael's case, there is actually another way that appears in MSDN going back to .Net 1.1, `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.RunClassConstructor(..)`.  See my answer for a working variation of Rafael's example.

Answer (score 12):

There is actually a way to force the initialization of the properties in this case.  The change requires adding a type parameter to the base class to represent the future subclass of the base class that will contain the fields to be initialized.  Then we can use the RuntimeHelpers.RunClassConstructor to ensure that the sub class static fields are initialized.

The following will yield the results that you are looking for:

```
class Subclass<TSubclass, T> 
{
    static Subclass()
    {
        Values = new List<Subclass<TSubclass, T>>();
        // This line is where the magic happens
        System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.RunClassConstructor(typeof(TSubclass).TypeHandle);
    }
    public Subclass()
    {
        if (!Values.Any(i => i.Value.Equals(this.Value)))
        {
            Values.Add(this);
        } 
    }

    public T Value { get; set; }

    public static List<Subclass<TSubclass, T>> Values { get; private set; }
}

class Superclass : Subclass<Superclass, int>
{
    public static Superclass SuperclassA1 = new Superclass { Value = 1 };
    public static Superclass SuperclassA2 = new Superclass { Value = 2 };
    public static Superclass SuperclassA3 = new Superclass { Value = 3 };
    public static Superclass SuperclassA4 = new Superclass { Value = 4 }; 
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        foreach (var value in Superclass.Values)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(value.Value);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

What is happening is, the call to `RuntimeHelpers.RunClassConstructor(typeof(TSubclass).TypeHandle)` forces the static constructor of `TSubclass` to execute if it has not already run.  This ensures that the static fields have initialized first as per this line from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645612(VS.71).aspx :

> If a class contains any static fields with initializers, those initializers are executed in textual order immediately prior to executing the static constructor.

Here is a dotnetfiddle demonstrating it working:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/MfXzFd

Comment: You saved my day sir. +1 from me.

Comment: @S.TarıkÇetin Happy to hear that this helped you!

Comment: That's amazing, it's quite close to what I actually need! The only thing that would top it would be if Superclass can be derived too and new field will be initialized as well. Like this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/RGBghM

The only way I know is to make `Superclass` which I don't want, cause this is my default implementation and `SuperClassCustom` are some specific customizations for a specific customer.

Comment: @Wolfsblvt Yes, sadly it won't pick up that subclass.  However, if the SuperClassCustom is merely providing alternate functionality, and it should be considered part of a whole set that can be enumerated on the Superclass, then this might work for you: https://dotnetfiddle.net/LW3D8u .  I simply moved the static instance of the SuperClassCustom up to the Superclass "enum".

Comment: Yeah, but the thing is that the SuperClassCustom does provide new functionality, so new properties and stuff. We can't touch the "core" files when we want to customize some things. That's the real issue here. Found a working solution though. Not nice, but it does the job. I am iterating over all assemblies and types once to call all static constructors if they derive from TSubclass: https://dotnetfiddle.net/C0BYCM

Answer (score 5):

But you're never setting the property -- instead you're setting the backing field directly, so not going through your logic to add to the static list when creating program1, program2 and program3.

i.e. you need to change:

```
    static Program program1 = new Program { value = 1 };
    static Program program2 = new Program { value = 2 };
    static Program program3 = new Program { value = 3 };
```

to:

```
    static Program program1 = new Program { Value = 1 };
    static Program program2 = new Program { Value = 2 };
    static Program program3 = new Program { Value = 3 };
```

Comment: This is why we don't use the same variable name for a member and a property name!

Comment: Of course, your code allows you to add the same instance to your list many times, so you might instead want to move the "add to static list" logic to the constructor or just check to see if it's already in the list...

Comment: Okay! My sample is broken. I mistyped the Value property by the value field. But sadly it is not what is happening in my actual code.

I will replace the sample for another one that is more like my actual code, using the constructor to add the instances to the Values list too.

I think it has something to do with what John Skeet describes here: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/01/26/type-initialization-changes-in-net-4-0.aspx

Thanks anyway!

Comment: @ Travis "This is why we don't use the same variable name for a member and a property name!" - actually you can use the same name an dit is a very common style in C#, but you would typically make the backing field private and only expose the property as public.

Comment: @Travis and Steve: I agree with Steve. I really don't like the other, underscored, pattern.

Comment: @Rafael: So you prefer there to be a logical mistake that isn't a compile time error when you make a subtle typo?  Interesting...

Comment: @Travis: As Steve said, it is only used for private fields, so it only affects the developer of the Type, who must be responsible for what he types.

Comment: For anyone stumbling over the broken link to Jon Skeet's blog in Rafael's comment above the new and working link is https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/01/26/type-initialization-changes-in-net-4-0/

Answer (score 2):

Actually looks you misspelled 'value' -> 'Value'
So:

```
    static Program program1 = new Program { Value = 1 };
    static Program program2 = new Program { Value = 2 };
    static Program program3 = new Program { Value = 3 };
```

pretty prints more lines

Answer (score 0):

The second sample doesn't work simply because `Value` is a static member of `Subclass`.

C# syntax allows `Superclass.Values`, but eventually the compiled method call will be to the `Subclass.Values` getter. So the type `Superclass` is never actually touched. `Superclass.SuperclassA1` on the other hand does touch the type and triggers the static initialization.

This is why C# doesn't really have implicit static initialization and you need composition frameworks like MEF and Unity.