# C# force static fields initialization

Tags: c#, enums, static, initialization

We are currently implementing some kind of "extensible enum class" based on strings. Only a part of this C# code is displayed below, to make the problem easier to understand.

If I run the code below, it writes "BaseValue1" and "BaseValue2" to the console.

If I uncomment the **RunClassConstructor** line and run the code, it additionally writes "DerivedValue1" and "DerivedValue2" to the console.
This is what I want to achieve, but I want to achieve it *without* the **RunClassConstructor** line.

I thought that **DerivedEnum.AllKeys** would trigger the creation of "DerivedValue1" and "DerivedValue2", but obviously this is not the case.

Is there a possibility to achieve what I want, without forcing the user of these "enum classes" to write some magic code, or to do some kind of dummy initialization?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            //System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.RunClassConstructor(typeof(DerivedEnum).TypeHandle);

            foreach (var value in DerivedEnum.AllKeys)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(value);
            }
        }
    }

    public class BaseEnum
    {
        private static readonly IDictionary<string, BaseEnum> _dictionary = new Dictionary<string, BaseEnum>();

        public static ICollection<string> AllKeys
        {
            get
            {
                return _dictionary.Keys;
            }
        }

        public static readonly BaseEnum BaseValue1 = new BaseEnum("BaseValue1");
        public static readonly BaseEnum BaseValue2 = new BaseEnum("BaseValue2");

        protected BaseEnum(string value)
        {
            _dictionary[value] = this;
        }
    }

    public class DerivedEnum : BaseEnum
    {
        public static readonly DerivedEnum DerivedValue1 = new DerivedEnum("DerivedValue1");
        public static readonly DerivedEnum DerivedValue2 = new DerivedEnum("DerivedValue2");

        protected DerivedEnum(string value)
            : base(value)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [When do static variables get initialized in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965976/when-do-static-variables-get-initialized-in-c), [Is there a way to force static fields to be initialized in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154697/is-there-a-way-to-force-static-fields-to-be-initialized-in-c), so you need to _instantiate_ `DerivedEnum` or access one of _its_ static members.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A static constructor is only invoked when the class is first accessed.

While you did used `DerivedEnum.AllKeys`, but it is simply inherited from `BaseEnum`. Therefore `DerivedEnum` were never directly referenced.

A little hack you could do is actually create a `new static` property on `DerivedEnum` that returns the same property from the base class, so when it is called the static constructor of the derived class will be invoked.

```
public class DerivedEnum : BaseEnum
{
   public new static ICollection<string> AllKeys
   {
       get
       {
           return BaseEnum.AllKeys;
       }
   }
}
```

**UPDATE**

You can also use `System.Reflexion` to dynamically invoke them :

```
public class BaseEnum
    static BaseEnum()
    {
        // from the types defined in current assembly
        Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().DefinedTypes
            // for those who are BaseEnum or its derived
            .Where(x => typeof(BaseEnum).IsAssignableFrom(x))
            // invoke their static ctor
            .ToList().ForEach(x => System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.RunClassConstructor(x.TypeHandle));
    }
}
```

You can also use this code to initialize derived class defined in other assemblies :

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
    .SelectMany(x => x.DefinedTypes)
    .Where(x => typeof(BaseEnum).IsAssignableFrom(x))
    .ToList().ForEach(x => System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.RunClassConstructor(x.TypeHandle));
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there also a solution where only a modification in the `BaseEnum` is necessary, so that the implementer of `DerivedEnum` doesn't have to take care implementing the new static property? Probably not, because the `BaseEnum` doesn't know all its derived classes...

Comment: You can also use `System.Reflexion` to dynamically invoke them See my update.

Comment: OK, this would be a nice solution if all derived classes would be in the same Dll as the `BaseEnum` class. In my code this is unfortunately not the case, because the users of our library might add own derived classes in additional Dlls.

Answer (score 1):

In C#, static members are initialized just before the first usage of the class. In your example, you are actually using a member of the base class `BaseEnum` and bypassing `DerivedEnum` which is causing only the static members of `BaseEnum` to be initialized.

You will need to implement the `AllKeys` property in your derived class. This will insure that the compiler uses the property in your derived class & initializes all of it's members.

And then add a new `AllKeys` property in your DerivedEnum to override the `AllKeys` of the `BaseEnum`.

```
new public static ICollection<string> AllKeys
{
    get
    {    
        return BaseEnum.AllKeys;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I guess you mean `AllKeys` _property_, not `AllKeys` _field_, right?

Comment: @MaDev Correct, thank you for pointing that out. I will update the answer.